# A score sequence of a tournament

Tags: graph-theory

How to show that if $s_1,s_2, \ldots, s_n $ is a score sequence of a tournament then $n-1-s_1,n-1-s_2, \ldots,n-1-s_n$  is a score sequence of a tournament

Comment: What if you reverse all the arrows?

Answer (score 0):

The tournament must have been a complete round robin for this to make sense with scores $1$ for a win, $0$ for a loss and maybe $1/2$ for a draw.  Let $S=\sum_is_i$.  This is the total number of games played because each game yields one total point.  The total score of the modified series is $n(n-1)-S$.  If the tournament is complete the total of all the scores is $\frac 12n(n-1)$, so if not all the games were played in the first version there would be too many games played in the second.  Now just reverse the result of every game and you are done.